# What British books can you recommend for advanced English studies?

Tags: learning-methods

I am in 11th grade and I am going to enter the university in the linguistic direction.  What would you advise from British textbooks to maximize my knowledge?
And one nore question.
What would you generally advise to read and learn for language learning?

Comment: You can post any questions related to language learning on [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Your university professors are the ones you should ask.

Comment: "I am in 11th grade" Please discuss with your teachers who know you as an individual.